# building boost libraries for ARM (to use on Windows Phone)

Tags: c++, boost, windows-phone-8

I am trying to build some boost libraries for ARM, and I got a bit stuck.

What I did:

Download boost 1_54 and extract it

Run BOOST_PATH/tools/build/v2/bootstrap.bat

Run .\bjam

So I have the libraries built, but they are for x86

Now, I did not get how to specify that I want to build all the libraries for `architecture=arm target-os=windows`

To be even more specific, I want libboost_chrono-vc90-mt-s-1_54.lib and libboost_chrono-vc90-mt-sgd-1_54 (and all the other libs) built, as I said before, for ARM, to use on Windows Phone.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I remember I used the libraries as header-only. Didn`t manage to compile them

Answer (score 0):

I have typically used b2 instead of bjam -- it accepts a variety of command line arguments, one of them being the target architecture.  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/bbv2/tasks.html#bbv2.tasks.crosscompile for more information.